# Sequence in 10-base decimal representation of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

For some time ago Wolfram launched [MyPiDay](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/03/12/pi-or-pie-celebrating-pi-day-of-the-centuryand-how-to-get-your-very-own-piece-of-pi/), which lets you find your 6-digit birthday string in the 10-base decimal representation of $\pi$. For example, my birthday string "970524" starts at the 137475th digit of $\pi$.

Now it's not known whether or not $\pi$ is a normal number, but to what extent has this conjecture been tested? That is: what is the largest natural $N$ we know, such that the decimal sequence

"$a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 \ldots a_n$", $\quad N > n$

occurs in the 10-base decimal representation of $\pi$, where $\{ a_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is an arbitrary sequence of naturals?

Comment: I think the question you want to ask is for what $N$ do we know all the decimal numbers up to $N$ occur in $\pi$.  I would guess somewhere between a billion and a trillion just because people check crazy things about $\pi$

Comment: @RossMillikan How does that differ from what I've asked?

Comment: For one given $N$ we know the answer.  Just take all the digits we know of $\pi$, which is in the trillions.  The last bit tries to say all numbers of that length have to be known to occur.  I was trying to make that clearer.  I would guess the length is around $10$, but have no specific evidence to support it.

Comment: @RossMillikan The length of what? The sequence? I'm talking about an arbitrary sequence in the decimal expansion of $\pi$.